# Unable to create list workflows in SharePoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I tried to create a list workflow in SPD 2010 and I got an error message:

`Unable to load workflow actions from the server. Please contact your system administrator.`

This is happening across all the sites. Cant we create list workflows in SPD 2010 for SP 2010 sites?

Comment: Please check you ULS logs and post the error message here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some custom solution in your farm which is causing the issue...

**Solution 1:**

1. Open web.config file path : **C:\Program Files\Common
   Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS** Change the following in web.config `<customErrors mode=**"Off**"/>`
2. In your site go to **site actions->site settings->site
   administration ->workflow** There it will show in which web part
   error is present.
3. Go to central administrator **system settings->farm
   management->manage farm solutions** there you will find all the
   deployed web parts.Just click on the error web part which was shown
   in above step.And click Retract solution and click ok.
4. Again go to your site error page(mentioned in step 2).Refresh the
   page. If there is no error means you can open workflow. Otherwise do
   it for next error webpart which was shown in that page

**Solution 2:**

Go to central administrator: **system settings->farm management->manage farm solutions**
I removed all web parts I've added recently, then IISRESET /noforce, then i checked , it worked fine with me , then i add all these webparts i added again , and still working fine

http://e-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2013/08/sharepoint-designer-2010-unable-to-load.html